# Get similiar/closest numbers from the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

I'm trying to find the efficient way of finding the similar numbers (where the difference between the numbers is "almost constant" - close to some constant).

For example having array like:

```
const arr = [23, 130, 142, 151, 163, 200];
```

would return a new array:

```
const similarNumbers = [130, 142, 151, 163];
```

Currently the way I try to solve it is to map through the first array and try to find smallest difference between the numbers and then map again and check if the absolute value of `currentValue - previousValue -  smallestGap < SOME_THRESHOLD`, but this is not ideal and only works in some of the particular cases.

Ideally what I'd like to achieve is for the function to return a few arrays with the grouped similar numbers:

```
const someArr = [23, 130, 142, 151, 163, 200, 232, 261];
```

would return two arrays:

```
group1 = [130, 142, 151, 163];
```

and:

```
group2 = [200, 232, 261];
```

Comment: Based on what?! Science and informatics are precise. We need accurate rules to solve this

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple (and not perfect) function I just wrote. It will group numbers into groups based on a threshold value which defines the maximum derivation from the groups average.

```js
const someArr = [23, 130, 142, 151, 163, 200, 232, 261];
var threshold = 50;

var relations = {};
var groups = {};


i = 0;
for (var j = 0; j < someArr.length; j++) {
  var number = someArr[j];
  if (i == 0) {
    relations[number] = i;
    groups[i] = [];
    groups[i].push(number);
  }
  else {
    var added = false;
    var n_groups = 0;
    for (var g in groups) {
      var sum = 0;
      var group = groups[g];
      if (group.length == 1 && Math.abs(number - group[0]) <= 2 * threshold) {
        relations[number] = parseInt(g, 10);
        groups[g].push(number);
        added = true;
      }
      else {
      for( var n = 0; n < group.length; n++ ){
          sum += group[n];
      }
      var avg = sum/group.length;
      if (Math.abs(number - avg) <= threshold) {
        relations[number] = parseInt(g, 10);
        groups[g].push(number);
        added = true;
      }
      }
      n_groups++;
    }
    if (!added) {
      var h = n_groups;
      relations[number] = parseInt(h, 10);
      groups[h] = [];
      groups[h].push(number);
    }
  }
  i++;
}

//console.log(relations, groups);

document.getElementById('grouped').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(groups);
```

```html
<h3>Input</h3><div id="original">[23, 130, 142, 151, 163, 200, 232, 261]</div>
<h3>Output</h3><div id="grouped"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's the result you want to obtain.

```
function(entries) {
  let groups = {};
  let finalGroups = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    let b = entries[i];
    let power = 0;
    while(b > 10) {
      power++;
      b = b / 10
    }

    groups[power] = groups[power] || []
    groups[power].push(a[i]);
  }

  for (let i in groups) {

    for (let j = 0; j < groups[i].length; j++) {
      const c = groups[i][j]
      const max = Math.floor(c / Math.pow(10, i));
      finalGroups[i] = finalGroups[i] || {};
      finalGroups[i][max] = finalGroups[i][max] || [];
      finalGroups[i][max].push(c);
    }
  }

  return finalGroups;
}
```

Here is the result. You will need to extract arrays but that's not the difficult part

```
{
  "1":
    {
      "2":[23]
    },
  "2":
    {
      "1":[130,142,151,163],
      "2":[200,232,261]
    }
 }
```

The function will firstly sort entries by their powers of 10. Then it will sort them by the number the most on the left.

So if you have values like `1030` and `1203` they will be considered as close values...

EDIT: Made a mistake. Fixed it

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to find two groups of numbers that are more alike with each other, for the simplest sets you can split them in half, and find the difference between the first/last items, and the difference between the item before/after that item, if its closer to the item in the other group, else leave them as they are

```js
const someArr = [23, 130, 142, 151, 163, 200, 232, 261];

someArr.sort((a, b) => a < b ? -1 : 1);

let groupA = someArr.slice(0, Math.ceil(someArr.length / 2))
let groupB = someArr.slice(Math.ceil(someArr.length / 2));

const differenceInA = Math.abs(groupA[groupA.length - 2] - groupA[groupA.length - 1]);
const differenceInB = Math.abs(groupB[0] - groupB[1]);
const differenceInBoth = Math.abs(groupA[groupA.length - 1] - groupB[0])

if (differenceInBoth < differenceInB) {
   groupA.push(groupB[0]);
   groupB = groupB.slice(1);
} else if(differenceInBoth > differenceInA) {
   groupB.unshift( groupA[groupA.length - 1]);
   groupA = groupA.slice(0, groupA.length - 1);
}

console.log('Group A:', groupA);
console.log('Group B:', groupB);
```

The above logs

```
Group A: [
  23,
  130,
  142,
  151,
  163
]
Group B: [
  200,
  232,
  261
]
```